# Fetching Records from to table with many to many relationship

Tags: postgresql

[image]

Dear folks,

I need a query the scenario is on the attached screen shot.

thank in advance

Comment: Are you using these tables on 3 different databases?

Comment: No they are in same database

Comment: Then remove unnecessary tags and keep one tag.. which database are you using..

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid,login,
       isnull([Entry],'') as Right1,
       isnull([Rev],'') as Right2,
       isnull([App],'') as Right3
from
(
select u.userid,u.login,t.name
from users_tbl u
join role_tbl r on r.userid=u.userid
join rights_tbl t on t.roleid=r.role_id
)p
pivot
(
max(name) for name in ([Entry],[Rev],[App])  
)
pvt
```

Try this code . hope it helps you getting the expected result.

Comment: The question has been tagged with `postgresql`. You are using `PIVOT` and `ISNULL()` and square brackets, so I suppose the answer is for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes pivot is in SQL server but i am using postgresql